# cordova Update files and reload updated index.html?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am working in a Plugin that does update of HTML files.

The default location from where cordova fetches files is from assests directory but this directory is read only, we cannot update the files in this directory.

So i moved this assests directory to files(/data/data/packagename/files) directory, Whenever there is a update occurred i was able to  download the zip bundle from server , extract the bundle using zip extractor and able to show the updated index.html from updated bundle.

The problem is how can i set the start Page location programmatically from updated bundle when App starts again likewise iOS "startPage()" method.

I do not want this to be achieved by updating config.xml  or  loadURL() in default cordovaApp.java.

Thanks